# Send emails from localhost with php

Tags: php, email, xampp, localhost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send email using GMail SMTP server from PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)

i followed this tutorial to config my php.ini on xampp to send emails from localhost to emails with domains like gmail, hotmail, etc.

However, when the code is executed (`mail("myemail","Success","Thanks, that works");`)
i got the following error:

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 530 Authentication required

Any hint what i could be doing wrong?

Comment: As the error says, the SMTP server you are using requires a user and password before allowing you to queue a mail to be sent. Please check where are you setting up the parameters to use a given SMTP server

Comment: That tutorial is not good. Try another one. Why don't you take this other one?

Comment: with that suggestion you give i need to config php.ini too?

Comment: http://www.websnippetz.blogspot.in/2013/01/send-email-from-xampp-localhost.html